# LabVIEW missing VI

Tags: labview

I'm trying to run a LabVIEW program that keeps bringing up an error saying it is missing a bunch of Sub VIs. I have most of the sub VIs in a separate folder except one : the NML ALL GPIB vi.  I think the rest of the VIs are not running becuase they are all connected to this one but I'm not sure. Can someone please tell me where I can download this specific VI? do I need to download a specific driver? which one? Thanks!

Comment: Related question [Missing driver LabVIEW](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6377958/186)

Answer (score 2):

Your missing VI looks like it interfaces with instruments using GPIB. It looks like this vi was created by Scott Hannahs, NHMFL-FSU, Nov. 1993. I'm not sure how it appears to be avaliable for download from his site as a [LabVIEW library file](http://sthmac.magnet.fsu.edu/downloads/labview/VIs%206.1/NML%20Data%20Acq%20LV6.1.0%20021017.llb). This library looks to hold all the subVIs required to allow the NML ALL GPIB vi to run but they may need to be linked into your project.

What is the function of your LabVIEW program? Have you inherited the code or is this a new development? If you need any help with LabVIEW in the future there are several resources you should be aware of.

1. [Info-LabVIEW](http://sthmac.magnet.fsu.edu/infolabview/index.html) - an independent mailing list to discuss the LabVIEW software produced by National Instruments
2. [LAVA](http://lavag.org/) - The LAVA Forums are managed and maintained by dedicated LabVIEW enthusiasts
3. [National Instruments](http://www.ni.com/) - National Instruments develop LabVIEW and a wide range of data acquisition hardware

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the help. I'm actually trying to run a prgram some one else wrote so I'm not entirely sure of what it does. I knwo we 're trying to record some voltage and current readings. Anyhow apparently there is a whole bunch of other vis missing. @nekomatic

Comment: Although they appear to be present in the Sub vi folder they dont open. they are Magnet Id, Hardware check, Plot Data and Print, Make Plot Lables, Plot it, Relabel It, Write File header, Record Analog Info, Fix Column Heading, Make Igor Label etc etc I tried googling them separatly but to no avail and I can't find them in the other links you gave me but maybe I'm not looking right. I think these all come from the same NI-DAQ driver. I know those are available on the national instruments website but I dont know which one to download. @nekomatic

Comment: the lab view I am using is a 64 bit Labview 2010. I am using Windows. Thanks! @nekomatic

Comment: You may need to add all the subVIs to your project. I don't think you can link the llb file directly so you may have to save each VI to your project folder. These VIs are not part of the National Instruments DAQ drivers, they look to have been created by Scott.

Comment: As Swinders says, I think these are part of a library created by Scott Hannahs at FSU, or at least made available by him, and not by NI. When you say they 'appear to be present in the subVI folder' do you mean you've got files with those names, but they don't open? Try adding .vi to their names and see if you can open them individually. If so, you'll need to update the VI's that call them with the new names. They may just be too old to open directly in LabVIEW 2010 though.

Answer (score 2):

I Googled 'nml all gpib vi' and it appears to be part of [this library](http://sthmac.magnet.fsu.edu/downloads/labview/VIs%206.1/NML%20Data%20Acq%20LV6.1.0%20021017.llb) which is on [Scott Hannahs' site](http://sthmac.magnet.fsu.edu/).