# Missing driver LabVIEW

Tags: labview, daq-mx

I'm trying to run a program written by someone else in LabVIEW. The program records voltage. However it won't open because it is missing subVIs.

Initially I thought that only one was missing and the rest weren't working becuase they were attached to it but after someone on this forum kindly found it for me the rest of the VIs still won't work so I think I need to download them again. However there are too many off them to get separately, also I tried googling them to no avail.

The subVIs are :  `Magnet Id, Hardware check, Plot Data and Print, Make Plot Lables, Plot it, Relabel It, Write File header, Record Analog Info, Fix Column Heading, Make Igor Label` etc etc (this is not a complete list).

I feel that I should download a DAQ from The National Instruments Website but I am not sure which one. I am using 64 bit LabVIEW 2010 on Windows. Can someone please help me pick out the correct driver?
       Thanks!

Comment: As a supplement to inquiring here on SO, check out the [National Instruments](http://forums.ni.com/) forums.

Comment: These SubVI names sound like if they are not standard VIs but actually form the program you're trying to run and all you got is the main VI that launches the rest.

Comment: Related question [LabVIEW missing VI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6297366/186)

Answer (score 3):

Just going from memory, those aren't NI VIs that I recognize, especially if the misspellings are in the original.

What hardware is this interfacing with?

You should still be able to open the main VI. It will not compile or run, since the subVIs are missing, but you should be able to open it and maybe get some clues about what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

The SubVIs all appear to be in the llb file so they should be available. I'm not sure how you can access the subVIs directly from the llb file so you may want to convert this to a project folder (this is the new way of creating libraries since version 8 I think). There are some pages on the NI website that may help, try [Converting an LLB to a Project Library](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361D-01/lvhowto/convert_llb_to_lib/) and then add this Project Library to your project.

From what I can see the VIs make use of the VISA drivers to communicate with the individual instruments so you should make sure you have this installed. You don't mention what version of LabVIEW 2010 you have but I think they should be provided even the Basic version, I know they are provided with the Professional Development System version.